# Image Co-Ordinate System Design

Tags: c#, .net, ios, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm diving into something without sufficient background, but I feel like there may be simple solutions that don't require me to have in depth knowledge of the topic.

What I am trying to do is have an image co-ordinate system. Basically the user will supply an image, like a house plan. They can then click on points in the image and create markers (like google maps). The next time they retrieve the map, all the markers they added before are there and they can add new ones.

I need to identify the points these markers are located on so I can store that information. I also need to be able to create a layer on the image that contains the markers and renders them in the exact locations they were placed.

I imagine the easiest way to do this is to use pixel co-ordinates...the rub here is that the image won't be a fixed size since there is a web application and an IPad application, so the co-ordinate system needs to work as long as the image is in the same size ratio.

The server size is .NET and as mentioned there is an IPad app, so the solution needs to be viable given that tech stack.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using pixel coordinates in absolute terms, you can use the 0 to 1 range. The top left corner is (0,0), bottom right is (1,1) and the center of the image is (0.5,0.5). This way not matter what image size (or zoom level) you have, the markers will always be in the same place.

Comment: I like this approach in principal and it works well for storing the info, but how would I identify where the user clicked with this method?

Comment: That will depend on the presentation technology, but all of them (Windows Forms, WPF, iOS) will provide you with some sort of component to display the image. For example, in WPF you have the Image component. The image component has a mouse down event that gives you the X,Y coordinates of where the mouse was clicked. In the simple case (no zoom involved), to compute the 0-1 range value, you just have to divide that coordinate by the width or height of the image. For example, in a 800x600 image, a click on pixel (100,120) translates to (0.125,0.2)

Comment: That makes sense. I'm marking this as the answer; I'll ask follow up questions if I get stuck on implementation details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is don't try to figure out the correlation between the actual image and the coordinates.  The only thing I would do is use the resolution of the image, aka 800x600 and use that for your grid.  Then overlay your markers using that grid on the image.  The points you'd remember would just be X and Y values and maybe a tag name/id.

Comment: The problem is that in applications like this it is very common that the consumer and the provider have different image sizes. The image in the server might have 800x600 pixels, but for bandwidth sake, the image that goes to the iPhone over the wire is 400x300.